# 8 issues when i create a basic view project kotlin on the android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile, kotlin-android

`8 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
7. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
8. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).`

I create a basic view project, i try to run, and this error is showed in the console.

it's my first experience with kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to upgrade the app compile version from 33 to 34 because latest version of different components like fragments require api level 34.

So for api level 34 you will need to upgrade some files after that your app will compile.

Here is my code you need to replace it with yours then no error will come. In android paste this and also change the app name with yours in place of `tweetsy`:

```
android {
namespace = "com.example.tweetsy"
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.tweetsy"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
      }
   }
 }
```

All othe code will same in build.gradle file

Comment: I have the same problem... I think it is like this out of the box.  You say to upgrade this or that... I'm an Android newbie and don't know how to accomplish points from your advice.

Comment: We as developers always work on latest Api versions so the current latest API version for android is 34. All latest android Kotlin libraries are supported for that version. For that you have to change your targetSDK and compileSDK version from 33 to 34. And also change the compileOptions and KotlinOptions as mentioned above otherwise it will give error. Just replace with yours and compile.